# Get the name of a silverlight control in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls

I have created a number of silverlight buttons thus:-

```
        string b = "Button";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = b+i.ToString();
            btn.FontSize += 2;

            btn.Content = "Click Me " ;
            btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
            stack.Children.Add(btn);
        }
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(stack);
```

In the button click event I want to get the name of the button that was pressed. I had hoped that 
`string snd = sender.ToString();` would yield the information but all it gives is System.Windows.Controls.Button. Can anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the text that is displayed on the button?

Comment: No the name of the button ie the name that is created with the code `btn.Name = b+i.ToString();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast `sender` to a button.

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    Console.WriteLine(btn.Name);
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted many thanks for a great and prompt answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var b = sender as Button;

    if (b != null)
    {
        var name = b.Name;
        // do something with name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(sender as Button).Name
```

[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsphone7series/thread/693a9015-cf47-4e2d-8375-46fb547aac3f)